# Not getting the email using Google Authentication in Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

I am using the code provided by Firebase for Google Authentication and somehow, the authentication was successful but the email was not correctly imported to Firebase.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/google-signin

As you can see in the screenshot below, the email is blank.  When I looked at the debugger, it is showing nil.
I clicked allow viewing email during authentication but I think there are still some settings that was not done correctly.  Could someone help me to take a look?  I am interested to use the email to create the username for each user.

[image]

```
func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInForUser user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: NSError!) {
    if let error = error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        return
    }

    let authentication = user.authentication
    let credential = FIRGoogleAuthProvider.credentialWithIDToken(authentication.idToken,
                                                                 accessToken: authentication.accessToken)
    FIRAuth.auth()?.signInWithCredential(credential) { (user, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error?.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        print("User logged in with Google...")
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("ToHome", sender: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: do you want to have multiple accounts with the same email?

Comment: I just disabled multiple accounts.  Now I am getting the email...thx...

Comment: It sounds like between the two of you, you have an answer. Can one of you write it up?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen just did it. I still have one doubt, can you confirm if my last paragraph make sense?

Comment: When in doubt, I'd remove that statement. ;-)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Right, but could you give me an exaplanation on how should the user work in the specific scenario? Thank you.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The email is not showing on firebase console because you are allowing users to create multiple accounts with the same email. If you navigate to **Auth -> Sign-in method** you can set the option to **Avoid creating multiple accounts with the same e-mail**. After doing so the emails will start to appear when creating the user.

[image: enter code here]

Not sure here but, **if you still want to create multiple accounts and have the user email on the application side** I guess that you will need to store the email on firebase database when creating the user.

Comment: I had "avoids creating multiple...." selected and a user still authenticated via Facebook without an email. Any other ideas why this would happen?

Comment: So, how can I get an e-mail from firebase when I allowing the creation of multiple accounts with the same email address?

Comment: @framled ... it's 3 years too late for the response..;-).. but I had the same problem and to get the email as the identifier in firebase you a can do this `this.googleProvider = new app.auth.GoogleAuthProvider(); this.googleProvider.addScope("email");` ... the addScope method worked for me

Answer (score -1):

You can search in list ProviderData:

userFirebase.providerData

The providerId "google.com" as usual have the email.