# Email was null when using Google login Firebase

Tags: node.js, vue.js

Email was null while using the Firebase Google login.

I tired out the below code:

```
googlesignin () {
    var baseProvider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
    firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(baseProvider)
    .then(function(result){
        console.log(result);
        console.log("Success..Google Account Linked");
    })
    .catch(function(err){
        console.log(err);
        console.log("Failed");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two options to help in your situation:

Instead of:

> console.log(result);

Try:

> console.log(result.email);

If the first option doesn't help you check this thread: [Not getting the email using Google Authentication in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37995180/not-getting-the-email-using-google-authentication-in-firebase)